# in one Jquery function, only call 2nd function one 1st function has returned result

Tags: jquery, function, wait

This is breaking my head, I have 2 functions
1) to get an ID
2) to call a second function with the ID which was retrieved.

Now I need to combine them in one function ,but obviously the 2nd function gets
called before GetSelectedID() has returned

```
function FillControl() {
        var iSelectedID  = GetSelectedID();
        SetControlValuesWithSelectedID(iSelectedID);
}

function GetSelectedID() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '123.ashx',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function (data1) {
                            return data1;
                    }
                });
            }
```

Please help to get the second function to be called only once first function has been called.

Comment: Won't that *already* do that for you?

Comment: Is `GetSelectedID()` asynchronous? Can you post the implementation of this function?

Comment: unfortunately not, the second function gets called before first function has returned the selectedID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `GetSelectedID()` function is asynchronous, as it performs an AJAX request. It will return immediately, but `iSelectedID` will only be available some time later.

You can pass a callback function to `GetSelectedID()`, call that function from the success callback passed to `$.ajax()`, and relocate the call to `SetControlValuesWithSelectedID` in that function:

```
function GetSelectedID(callback)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '123.ashx',
        data: PassingObj,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(data1) {
            callback(data1);
        }
    });
}
```

Then:

```
function FillControl()
{
    GetSelectedID(function(iSelectedID) {
        SetControlValuesWithSelectedID(iSelectedID);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Incorporate a callback function. to your GetSelectedID function.

Callback functions are useful when you need to fire a second function synchronously after your first function finishes running.

```
function GetSelectedID(callback){
   // everything this function does
   var params = result;
   if(typeof(callback) == "function"){   // check if a callback was supplied
      callback(params);                  // run callback with your ID
   }
   return params; // also useful to return data in any case.
}
```

and in your normal code:

```
function FillControl() {
    GetSelectedID(function(params){
       SetControlValuesWithSelectedID(params);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the 2nd function inside the ajax success callback

```
GetSelectedID(function(iSelectedID){SetControlValuesWithSelectedID(iSelectedID);});
function GetSelectedID(callback) {
    $.ajax({ url: '123.ashx', 
        data: PassingObj, type: 'POST', contentType:  'application/json', 
        success: function (id) { 
            if(callback)
                callback(id);
        } 
    }); 
}
```

If you want to get a return value from that function (`id = GetSelectedID()`) you'll have to make a synchronous call (`async: false`)

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: the problem is that GetSelectedID() is a generic function which needs to be called from a lot of functions ,and does not necessarily need to to anything afterwards e.g. it gets used as part of a parameter e.g    var PassingObj = new Object(); PassingObj.ID = GetSelectedID();